# Linq query skip querying null coditions

Tags: linq

I am very new to `linq`. I have my **clients** table. I want to select clients depending on the two conditions

1. Client type
2. Client city

So I can write the query like

```
from c in clients
where c.Type == cType
&& c.City == cCity
```

Can I use this same query to get the result only providing client type(ignoring the City condition. somithing like `*`).

What I want to do is if cCity or cType is **null** ignore the condition.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what you're looking for?

```
from c in clients
where (c.Type == null || c.Type == cType)
&& (c.City == null || c.City == cCity)
```

Comment: I want if `cType==null` skip querying that condition

Comment: when c.Type is null the whole result of (c.Type == null || c.Type == cType) is True, Therefore it is replaced by True so it skips that and checks next condition chain.. and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a LINQ statement before actually executing it:

```
if (cType != null)
    clients = clients.Where(c => c.Type == cType);
if (cCity != null)
    clients = clients.Where(c => c.City== cCity);
// At this point the query is never executed yet.
```

Example of how the query can be executed for the first time :

```
var results = clients.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from c in clients
where (cType == null ? 1 == 1 : c.Type == cType)
&& (cCity == null ? 1 == 1 : c.City == cCity)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is benefit of hardcoding `true` value as `1 == 1`? And benefit of ternary operation when it returns boolean value VS simple OR condition

Comment: It something similar to @Gert answer. 1 == 1 is always true i.e. we are skipping the condition if cType or cCity is null.

Comment: I know that `1 == 1` is always true. Why not to write `true` instead: `cType == null ? true : c.Type == cType`? If cType is null, then we return `true` else we return `c.Type == cType`. But that is how OR works: `cType == null || c.Type == cType`. So, questions are still here.

Comment: oh I misunderstood the question. Yup you are right we can have true there.